# JSON object parsing for text and image

Tags: android, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse the following JSON string returned by `httpResponse`:

```
{ "message" : "List of top ten checkin Men.",
  "success" : "True",
  "top_ten_checkin_men" : [ { "City_name" : "Mumbai",
        "is_block" : "no",
        "is_favorite" : "no",
        "is_friend" : "no",
        "last_step_in" : "Pride Hotels",
        "online" : "1",
        "points" : "3800",
        "request_pending" : "no",
        "user_thumbphoto" : "",
        "userage" : "26",
        "userbodytype" : "3",
        "userfname" : "John",
        "usergender" : "Male",
        "userid" : "191",
        "userlname" : "Aarmani",
        "userlookingfor" : "Female",
        "useronlinestatus" : "Yes",
        "userphoto" : ""
      },
      { "City_name" : "New York",
        "is_block" : "no",
        "is_favorite" : "no",
        "is_friend" : "no",
        "last_step_in" : "The House of MG",
        "online" : "1",
        "points" : "4450",
        "request_pending" : "no",
        "user_thumbphoto" : "http://anburaj.com/lockme/uploads/users/188/thumb_121840970.jpg",
        "userage" : "31",
        "userbodytype" : "3",
        "userfname" : "Williams",
        "usergender" : "Male",
        "userid" : "188",
        "userlname" : "Johens",
        "userlookingfor" : "Female",
        "useronlinestatus" : "Yes",
        "userphoto" : "http://anburaj.com/lockme/uploads/users/188/121840970.jpg"
      }
    ]
}
```

and so on.

What I should I take for `jsonarray` and what should be gone for `jsonobject`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[] defines a `JSONArray` (for instance `top_ten_checkin_men`).  {} defines a `JSONObject`.

It's worth to take the time to know about the JSON format [here](http://www.json.org/):

[image: http://json.org/array.gif]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"[]" represent array and "{}" is an object

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a `JSONObject` with success and message fields and a `JSONArray` top_ten_checkin_men

So something like :

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(yourString);
String message = json.getString("message");
String success = json.getString("success");
JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("top_ten_checkin_men");
```

should do what you want

Comment: Parsing is good. I'd just check if json is null before calling `getString`on it, you never know :)